# Getting height in JavaScript not working properly on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote a code to have a second div match the height of the first div. However, it doesn't work when refreshing the page. For example, if the first div has a height of 10000px, on refresh, the alerted height ranges from 5000px-8000px instead of 10000px. Keep in mind that the code below is just an example to illustrated the problem, and is not the original code. The original code retrieves data from mySQL.

```
<?php
include("ajaxLink.php");
?>

<style>
#totalWrap {
height: 10000px;
width: 25%;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid red;
}
#matchTotalWrap {
width: 25%;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>

<div id = "totalWrap"></div>
<div id = "matchTotalWrap"></div>

<script>
$(function(){

var matchHeight = $("#totalWrap").height()+"px";
alert(matchHeight);
$('#matchTotalWrap').css("height",matchHeight);

});
</script>
```

**PS:**  It works perfectly when you re-enter the link in the address bar.

Comment: @divy3993 I thought $(function) was a shortcut for that?

Comment: Sorry i didn't see that you have `$(function() {.....});`

Comment: @divy3993 This only happens on refresh. Re-entering the link above in the address bar works fine every time for some reason.

Comment: So do you get exact height or **`outer-height`**?

Comment: _"original code retrieves data from mySQL"_ if you are doing an ajax request in javascript and then setting/getting the height you should include that code

Comment: @divy3993 If the height of the first div is 10000px, I expected the height of the second div to also be 10000px.

Comment: It's little unusal, i guess it's the case of cache. Else you can go with @PatrickEvans's way using `ajax/javscript`

Comment: @PatrickEvans No, not doing ajax request.

Comment: @divy3993 I kind of suspected that too, but is that a way to fix it?

Comment: For instace try in different device's or browser's, and see what does it do.

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example then, as your current example doesn't reproduce your problem

Comment: Or better if you can provide link if it's live.

Comment: @divy3993 Sure. Here's the link. https://www.iscattered.com/design.php

Comment: It's really really strange.

Comment: Looks like loading the images is changing the div sizes... can't say for sure that's the problem, but at least that's a start. Maybe try loading the page without images and see if the problem persists?

Comment: The page you linked to doesnt have #totalwrap having a `height: 10000px;` property in the css